# How to show only one video from multiple videos on Anki Card

Tags: anki

I have cards where a back note has multiple sound tags with video files. I want only one of them to be randomly selected and appear on the card. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to do this.

Comment: Please post your code as text so we can copy and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with this solution:

Front / Back Template

```js
// "soundLink": Anki desktop | "replaybutton": AnkiDroid
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".soundLink, .replaybutton");

if (buttons) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length);
  buttons[randomIndex].classList.add("active");
}
```

CSS

```css
.soundLink,
.replaybutton {
  display: none;
}

.soundLink.active,
.replaybutton.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```